# For doesn't restart (does one time) in csv file in python

Tags: python, csv, for-loop

I've a problem with reading and compring two csv files in Python. In particular, this is what I wrote:

```
with open("cache.csv", "r+") as cache_csv:
    writer = csv.writer(cache_csv)
    leggi = csv.reader(cache_csv)
    next(leggi)
    with open('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/size.csv') as f:
      reader = csv.reader(f)  
      header = next(reader)
      if header != None:
          for row in reader:
                for compare_row in leggi:
                    if compare_row[0] == row[0]:
                        print (row[0], 'is equal to', compare_row[0])
                    else:
                        print (row[0], 'is not equal to', compare_row[0])
```

I'm trying to compare the first column of the two csv files but it results:

```
UmZgHu4g0YU is equal to UmZgHu4g0YU 
UmZgHu4g0YU is not equal to 4z_3v0atqk0 
UmZgHu4g0YU is not equal to z5R2NXcm6cQ
```

but **reader** consists of 49999 rows while **leggi** just 3. So the first for doesn't restart. How can I solve it? Thank you very much, I hope someone can help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the iterator `leggi` is empty after the first 3 elements.
Try converting the iterator `leggi` into a list and slice it to skip the first element.

```
leggi = csv.reader(cache_csv)
leggi_list = list(leggi)[1:]
```

You can then iterate over the leggi_list instead of the iterator.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, which solves my problem!